# XAML GridView Datatrigger won't update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have this XAML in a WPF project.

```
       <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredApps}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedApp, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Image}">
                            <Image>
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="{x:Static common:Globals+ModelState.Unedited}">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Resources/IndraDoc/AppUnedited.png"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="{x:Static common:Globals+ModelState.Edited}">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Resources/IndraDoc/AppEdited.png"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="{x:Static common:Globals+ModelState.New}">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Resources/IndraDoc/AppNew.png"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="{x:Static common:Globals+ModelState.Deleted}">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Resources/IndraDoc/AppDeleted.png"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Namn"  Width="Auto"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

When property "Name" changes the appropriate change is displayed in the Grid, but when the property "State" changes the Image is not switched. Any takes on this?

**EDIT**
Strange thing is this, I edited the XAML and added the image outside of the ListView bound it to the SelectedApp instead, this works fine, however that was not the intended functionality. It will work for now, but I am still curious as to why my original code won't trigger.

Adding the code where I do the statechange:

```
   private void ChangeStateOnSelected(Globals.ModelState newState)
    {
        if (SelectedApp.State != newState) //dont do any changework if new state is same as current sate
        {
            if (SelectedApp.State == Globals.ModelState.New && newState == Globals.ModelState.Edited) //this is not allowed
                return;
            SelectedApp.State = newState;
            if (newState == Globals.ModelState.Unedited)
            {
                var selectedId = SelectedApp.Id;

                _allApps.Replace(_allApps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == SelectedApp.Id), SelectedApp);
                _selectedApp = (Data.DataModel.App)_locationService.GetApp(selectedId);
                _filteredApps.Replace(_filteredApps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == SelectedApp.Id), SelectedApp);
            }
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedApp);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AllApps);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FilteredApps);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note: 
I am using Caliburn Micro and behind the scene when changing the values I am calling NotifyPropertyChange() on SelectedApp and FilteredApps.

Comment: Why do you set the DataType of the DataTemplate to DataType="{x:Type Image}"? I guess your data item in the ItemsSource of the ListView is not a System.Windows.Controls.Image.

Comment: That was a copy-paste mistake this has now been changed to: <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:App}">
the result remains the same though.

Comment: You might want to show how and when you are actually setting the State property and how and where it is implemented then because your bindings look allright.